# VSCode with Python and Cygwin

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am using Cygwin in Windows 7 (no choice - work computer) for Python development.

I'm trying to get Visual Studio Code to use Python virtual environments (created using Cygwin), without success.

The problem seems to be that VSCode will only find virtualenvs created using Powershell, i.e. where the venv folder contains a `Scripts` folder, instead of the `bin` folder created when creating a new virtualenv using Cygwin (understandable, I guess...)

I was wondering if there was a way to either get VSCode to recognise the 'bash' version of the virtualenv, or to create a virtualenv that could be activated in both Cygwin and VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the extension does not have support for cygwin. Probably the closest you will get is tracking the [issue for WSL support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/67) (which I know doesn't solve your Win7+cygwin situation).